# Does split work inside pig macros?

Tags: macros, apache-pig

I get

```
Undefined alias: ZZ
```

error on this macro:

```
define chop (my, name, maxev) returns grouped, massive {
  gr = foreach (group $my by id) generate group as id, $name;
  split gr into
    massive if COUNT($name) > $maxev,
    ZZ otherwise;
  $grouped = ZZ;
  $massive = foreach massive generate id, COUNT($name) as $name;
};
A, massive = chop(A, 'abc', '$MAX_EVENTS');
```

When I try

```
  split gr into
    massive if COUNT($name) > $maxev,
    $grouped otherwise;
```

instead, I get

```
Macro 'chop' missing return alias: grouped
```

Comment: `$grouped = ZZ;` is not a proper Pig statement.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus: what should I use instead?

Comment: If you just want to duplicate an alias, you'd have to do `X = FOREACH Y GENERATE *;`